# What do I put in front of my query to update a field

Tags: query, field-update

Opportunity is the master and CustomObject is detail with multiple CustomObjects linked to one Opportunity. I want to update OpportunityField to equal CustomObjectField from the most recent CustomObject.
I think I have the SOQL correct, but I'm not sure what to do in front of or after it to make the field update.

```
trigger somethingrandom on Opportunity (before insert) 
{
    OpportunityField var = [
        SELECT CustomObjectField 
        FROM CustomObject 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate
        DESC LIMIT 1 //last two lines to pick the most recent CustomObject            
    ];
}
```

This just gives me an error "Invalid Type: OpportunityField". 
[Both of them are numbers, although one is Number(6,0) and the other is Number (18,0)]
I also feel like I need a WHERE so that I'm only getting CustomObjects that are linked to the Opportunity, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this even bulk friendly?

Comment: If CustomObject has a master-detail relationship to Opportunity as the master then there won't be any CustomObject records in the database until after the Opportunity has inserted. I.e. You can't use a before insert trigger on the Opportunity, as the CustomObject records won't exist yet.

Comment: Do you want this trigger to fire based on the Opportunity being updated, or a CustomObject being created/updated?

Comment: Opportunity is the Master, Custom Object is the detail.

Comment: I think best practice would be the CustomObject being created/updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this -- note bulk-aware as suggested by previous commenters; note after trigger as you need the ids of the Opportunities to do updates.

Looking at your initial question, I might suggest reviewing the Apex Developers Guide - especially the examples on how to write trigger correctly.

Note also I skipped try-catch blocks or partial success processing for clarity.

Note also this will only execute when the Oppo changes value - not when a customObject__c is CRUD'd - if you are trying to sync the Oppo to the most recent custom object, you need to give the Oppo trigger a reason to execute such as:

- A trigger (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) on CustomObject__c sets a custom field value on parent Oppo - 'is_enabled_for_sync__c'
- A workflow on CustomObject_c does a field update on parent Oppo (although won't work for deletes and undeletes)
- There is a RSF field on Oppo that sums/counts childObject__c causing the Oppo trigger to fire

  ```
  trigger myOppoUpdateTrigger (after insert, after update) {

   // Step 1 - build map of all Oppos and the most recent child obj
   Map<ID,Opportunity> oIdToOppoWCustomObjsMap = new Map<ID,Opportunity> (
    [select id, oppoCustomField__c, (select id, customObjFld__c 
                  from CustomObjects__r
                  order by createdDate desc limit 1)
      from Opportunity where id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]);

   // Step 2 -- go through map and set value in Oppo from child; note that some oppos may have no children       
   for (Opportunity o : oIdToOppoWCustomObjsMap.values())
     o.oppoCustomField__c = o.customObjects__r.size() > 0 
                            ? o.customObjects__r[0].customObjFld__c
                            : null;
   // Step 3 - do DML to update all oppos
   update oIdToOppoWCustomObjsMap.values();
  }
  ```